# Can "must" be used in this specific situation?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct:

> I MUST go to a party.

Consider this sentence as a sentence that is out of context. If it's not proper, when it would be? What sentence it should then be followed by? Or in what situation it is correct?

Comment: One could think of many reasons why one might say that one ***must go to a party***. The doctor just told you that unless you live a more active social life you will probably die of boredom. So it seems *you (absolutely) must go to a party*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, why would it not be correct? You're saying it is necessary for you to go to a party. It could be because your mother insists that you should socialise with people, or that you feel your celebration of Liberation Day will be a failure if you don't find some party to attend, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say

*I have to go to a party.*

There are some teachers of EFL/ESL texts  which claim *have to* refers to external  motivation  and that *must*,  as in your sentence, refers to internal motivation. This distinction seems to work in some cases. In other cases the two seem synonymous:

In

*I must go to the party tonight. I simply have to meet Sam Spade*

it  seems both verbs refer to internal motivation.